# Display friend Facebook on IOS

Tags: facebook, storyboard, fbrequest-form

I have trouble displaying list friend facebook, I'm using FBRequest, I have already get list friend but it's not showing in UITableView

Here is my code:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tblView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tblView setDelegate:self];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadFirst];
        _itemsNamesFriend = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

            FBRequest *friendRequest = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:@"me/friends"];

            [friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                NSDictionary *resultDictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;
                _itemsNamesFriend = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
                NSLog(@"%@",_itemsNamesFriend); //--> have data

            }];

            NSLog(@"%@",_itemsNamesFriend); //--> data is empty
            [self.tblView reloadData];
        }

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//    NSLog(@"%d",_itemsNamesFriend.count);
    return _itemsNamesFriend.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any modification done to variables inside the block don't show outside of it. So, you need to declare them with __block for the modifications done inside the block to be visible outside.

This is what you need to do in your .h file

```
__block NSMutableArray* _itemsNamesFriend;
```

That should solve you problem.